# Boolean array returning empty instead of false

Tags: arrays, boolean

I am working on a program and I want a Boolean array to return the status of the seats.

```
False = empty. 

boolean seats [] = new boolean[10];
for(int i = 0; i<seats.length; i++)
       seats [i] = false;
for(int c = 0; c<seats.length; c++)
   while (seats[c] = false)
       System.out.printf("Seat %d is empty\n",c);
```

I would like this array to return.

```
Seat 1 is empty
Seat 2 is empty
Seat 3 is empty
[...]
```

How do I make false return string empty.

Thank you

Comment: at least take your time to properly formulate your question and format your code...

Comment: Hi John, as the question is, it is hard to understand what you want, try to edit the question so it gets more objective. Also, it is helpful include the language of the code

Comment: Arrays don't "return" anything, they're just a structure for holding values.  Your code can interpret those values any way you want.  Perhaps instead of an array you want to create an _object_ (which internally contains an array, most likely) which exposes values derived from the array?

Comment: Thank you guys for commenting. I am struggling a bit with the arrays so I am grateful for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
boolean seats [] = new boolean[10];
for(int i = 0; i<seats.length; i++){
  seats [i] = false;
}
for(int c = 0; c<seats.length; c++){
  if (false == seats[c]){
    System.out.printf("Seat %d is empty\n",c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your comparison you need to use == not =.

By the way your code is poorlry written. No need of while loop inside for loop. An if should be used, else it will be in infinite loop